# In python, how to remove duplicate values for a list of dictionary inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

My 1st set of data from database looks like:

```
[
    {u'ip': u'13.82.28.61', u'scanid': 1000, u'port': 443},
    {u'ip': u'206.190.36.45', u'scanid': 1001, u'port': 80},
    {u'ip': u'98.139.180.149', u'scanid': 1001, u'port': 80},
    {u'ip': u'98.138.253.109', u'scanid': 1001, u'port': 80},
    {u'ip': u'91.198.174.192', u'scanid': 1002, u'port': 110},
    {u'ip': u'91.198.174.192', u'scanid': 1002, u'port': 31337}
]
```

I need data according to `scanid`, such as:

```
{
    scanid : [{ip : [port1, port2 ...]}, {ip2 : [port3 ...]}],
    scanid : [{ip3 : [port1, port2 ...]}, {ip4 : [port3 ...]}],
    ...
}
```

Here IP's inside a `scanid` should not repeat. For example,

```
{
    1000: [{u'13.82.28.61': [443]}],
    1001: [{u'206.190.36.45': [80]}, {u'98.139.180.149': [80]}, {u'98.138.253.109': [80]}], 
    1002: [{u'91.198.174.192': [110, 31337]}]
}
```

I tried the code below:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
dictionary_with_scanid = defaultdict(list)
for rs in resultset:
    scanid = rs['scanid']
    domain = rs['ip']       
    port = rs['port']
    d[domain].append(port)
    dictionary_with_scanid[scanid].append({domain:d[domain]})
```

But I got repeated data for `scanid=1002`:

```
{
    1000: [{u'13.82.28.61': [443]}],
    1001: [{u'206.190.36.45': [80]}, {u'98.139.180.149': [80]}, {u'98.138.253.109': [80]}], 
    1002: [{u'91.198.174.192': [110, 31337]}, {u'91.198.174.192': [110, 31337]}]
}
```

This is my 2nd set of data, but `scanid 1002` has the same repeated data:

```
1002: [{u'91.198.174.192': [110, 31337]}, {u'91.198.174.192': [110, 31337]}]
```

I want the data below which does not feature repetition, either from the 1st set of data or from second set:

```
{
    1000: [{u'13.82.28.61': [443]}],
    1001: [{u'206.190.36.45': [80]}, {u'98.139.180.149': [80]}, {u'98.138.253.109': [80]}], 
    1002: [{u'91.198.174.192': [110, 31337]}]
}
```

Comment: If the IPs inside each scanid are supposed to be unique, why not just use a _single_ dictionary instead of a list of dictionaries with one key each?

Comment: If you cant have duplicates then use a set of dictionaries instead of a list of dictionaries

Comment: First of all - it is __way__ more probable to get an answer to your question if you make it more generic. Your question has nothing to do with IPs, ports or domains. It is about removing duplicates from nested dictionaries so why not make up a simpler example instead of pasting your actual code with long values, variables' names etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nesting too much, just use a single dict for each `scanid`. I'm using `setdefault` here, but you can achieve a similar result with `defaultdict` too:

```
data = ... # your original data 
scans = {}
for d in data:
    scans.setdefault(d['scanid'], {}).setdefault(d['ip'], []).append(d['port'])
print scans
```

Result:

```
{1000: {u'13.82.28.61': [443]}, 
 1001: {u'206.190.36.45': [80], 
        u'98.139.180.149': [80], 
        u'98.138.253.109': [80]}, 
 1002: {u'91.198.174.192': [110, 31337]}}
```

The `defaultdict` setup is a little tricky since you need to nest them; you need to pass the outer dict a custom function that constructs the inner one:

```
from collections import defaultdict
scans = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for d in data:
    scans[d['scanid']][d['ip']].append(d['port'])
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thanks a lot. Can you please explain the code a little bit?

Comment: Please post the code using defaultdict() too. I tried a lot with defaultdict() but couldn't make it.

Comment: @m.j Added;  that's understandable since it's not very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I would just make `dictionary_with_scanid` to be a dictionnary of dictionnaries to avoid IP duplication:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
dictionary_with_scanid = defaultdict(dict)  # use dict instead of list
for rs in resultset:
    scanid = rs['scanid']
    domain = rs['ip']
    port = rs['port']
    d[domain].append(port)
    # just use the previously updated d[domain] for dictionary_with_scanid[scanid]
    dictionary_with_scanid[scanid][domain] = d[domain]
```

It gives as expected:

```
pprint.pprint(dict(dictionary_with_scanid))
{1000: {'13.82.28.61': [443]},
 1001: {'206.190.36.45': [80], '98.138.253.109': [80], '98.139.180.149': [80]},
 1002: {'91.198.174.192': [110, 31337]}}
```